# Handling form validation inside modal window (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

What is the best way to achieve something like this in Wordpress?

We have a form inside modal window which should be validated before submission (and if it is not valid, modal should stay open). Currently, I'm handling forms with admin-post.php, and inside my hook I'm triggering validation - but admin-post action is already called before validation.

I've tried to use jQuery, and to prevent default event of submission (but admin-post hook is never called and validation is not triggered).

```
<script>
   $("form").submit(function(e) {
       alert("submitted");
       e.preventDefault();
   });
</script>
```

Comment: With `e.preventDefault` you are canceling the default action of the submit event. You can not expect anything else to happen at this point, if you don’t actively _do_ something else after that.

Comment: What is the other way to prevent modal from closing if validation fails?

Comment: Without seeing some more code to see how your modal works (see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to learn how to share code here with us) we can't help. Please update your question and include all relevant code so we can see it in action and maybe provide some suggestions.